# Where is the “energy” analogy coming from in PCA?

Tags: pca, terminology

In some publications or materials on POD/PCA, I've encountered sentences like: *the first PCs carry most **energy***, or *the first PCs identify the most **energetic** directions*. This analogy to *energy* seems like it’s coming from some very particular, maybe physics-related usage of PCA/POD. I would like to understand the origins of this analogy, mostly out of curiosity.

**Example:**

> The sum of the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix is defined as the “energy” of the data. A commonly used criterion for selecting the number of modes to keep in a low-dimensional representation is that of capturing a certain percentage of the energy of the data.

Source: [Frouzakis, C.E., Kevrekidis, Y.G., Lee, J., Boulouchos, K. and Alonso, A.A., 2000. Proper orthogonal decomposition of direct numerical simulation data: Data reduction and observer construction. Proceedings of the Combustion Institute, 28(1), pp.75-81.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0082078400801976)

Comment: could you provide some links as it does sound very context dependent

Comment: It's all about magnitude. Specifically, in PCA, magnitude as sum-of-squares. And it is all argot words. "Inertia", "Energy", and, when the data have been centered, we call it "Variability".